# What is the mask for emails using swing's MaskFormatter

Tags: java, swing, mask

Using Java swing, what is the string that correspond to a correct email mask when using the [`MaskFormatter`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html)?
Is that possible at all to actually use a `MaskFormatter` for emails?

Answer (score 1):

As much as it does make sorta sense to use a MaskFormatter, I don't think it is the most logical answer.  Because the length of an email address can vary greatly before and after the @ sign. So you could give the MaskFormatter a huge upper limit of 255 * before and after the @ sign, but that would create some hideous code.  I would suggest [validating the email address](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=180) on submit or something along those lines.  Hope that helps.